# How do I check the health of vue router system?, may be something is missing

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In this example I do not understand what is missing the my vue router system?
If you click in About link nothing happend, and it should show the about page handled by vue routing system

https://codesandbox.io/s/23v7v1pvwr

Comment: is there any errors in your console?

Comment: When posting questions to this site, it is usually very helpful for the people trying to answer you question, to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of your question. Working through all of your project code is very time consuming for someone not familiar with it and while working on your example for the question you might event find the solution to your problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and there is no visible error in console, only that the link do not respond as it is supposed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Vue world. Be ready, you have a lot to learn.

I have see that you have selected [parcel](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-parcel-197eb85a2c8c) as builder.
I prefer [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) as recommended from Vue.

After see that Vue was not loading and i have read how to [add Vue to a web with parcel](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-parcel-197eb85a2c8c).
I make Vue router works, but nothing more:
https://codesandbox.io/s/38wo1p9yn6
The page remove all JS when loads, maybe it a problem in parcel+condesandbox [this example is also not working](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/parcel-bundler/examples/tree/master/vue?from-embed).

I recommend you move your project [Vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) or the [code sandbox based on Vue-cli](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue).

Also, read the Vue and Vue-router docs to understand how to use it, seems that you need more time on this to build a web.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, the vue word is amazing. My original code was implemented upon vue-cli "framework" base offcorse in webpack. But to show a "working" example I copied it to the sandbox directly. I have read all the doc of vue routers. Whatever, I will review my code and will tell you what has happend.

Comment: Finally It works, I have to look close to code to discover a missing reference. Thanks a lot!!! Have a nice day